# How to add new columns to Web Api XML Documentation (help page)?

Tags: .net, xml, asp.net-web-api, xml-documentation

I'm working with the latest Web Api XML Documentation provided by nuget in Visual Studio 2012. Actually I'm doing my XML comments and I can get a help page of a class with this kind of properties:

```
Name  
Description  
Type  
Additional information
```

**I'm wonder if can I add one more to insert an example of the data, but I can't find the model in my comments.**

I do the following:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// My description
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>My example</example>
```

but it just doesn't appear.

I understand that I need to change the model loaded in `Parameters.cshtml` in order to show it in the html (that is not a problem) but...

**How can I change this model?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually I could solve it, I'll answer it when I have a little of time. Anyway if you want to response this question, I'll vote up and / or accept it.

Comment: could you please show us how you selved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web API has no support for doing this so you will have to build it up yourself. While it's not that difficult, you should consider first if adding the example to the description itself won't get the job done good enough.

The View, where you should add the 3rd column:

```
Areas/HelpPage/Views/Help/DisplayTemplates/ApiGroup.cshtml
```

Relevant snippet:

```
@foreach (var api in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="api-name"><a href="@Url.Action("Api", "Help", new { apiId = api.GetFriendlyId() })">@api.HttpMethod.Method @api.RelativePath</a></td>
        <td class="api-documentation">
        @if (api.Documentation != null)
        {
            <p>@api.Documentation</p>
        }
        else
        {
            <p>No documentation available.</p>
        }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Quickly you then realize you need look at the `ApiDescription` model.

The most relevant properties of `ApiDescription` seem to be:
- `ParameterDescriptions` (collection of parameters. Exposes: `Name, Source, Documentation`)
- `ResponseDescription`

These are the basics. In order to implement a proper help page this url will also prove a lot of use:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/12/10/asp-net-web-api-help-page-part-3-advanced-help-page-customizations.aspx

Below is my very basic implementation which lists parameter `name` and `source`

```
<h2 id="@Model.Key.ControllerName">@Model.Key.ControllerName</h2>
@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerDocumentation))
{
    <p>@controllerDocumentation</p>
}
<table class="help-page-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>API</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Params</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var api in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="api-name"><a href="@Url.Action("Api", "Help", new { apiId = api.GetFriendlyId() })">@api.HttpMethod.Method @api.RelativePath</a></td>
                <td class="api-documentation">
                    @if (api.Documentation != null)
                    {
                        <p>@api.Documentation</p>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p>No documentation available.</p>
                    }
                </td>
                <td class="api-documentation">
                    @foreach (var p in api.ParameterDescriptions)
                    {
                        @p.Name @:- @p.Source
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I solved it, but I don't have time to answer myself. (As appears in my first comment) And I have to make some more several modifications but this is currently a good helping answer.